# Attempting to use IE 10 on Virtual Box using WIndows 7

Tags: html, virtualbox, internet-explorer-10

Failed to import appliance C:/Users/Stephanie/Downloads/IE10.Win7.For.Windows.VirtualBox/IE10 - Win7.ova.

Could not create the imported medium 'C:\Users\Stephanie\VirtualBox VMs\IE10 - Win7\IE10 - Win7-disk1.vmdk'.

VMDK: Compressed image is corrupted 'C:\Users\Stephanie\IE10 - Win7-disk1.vmdk' (VERR_ZIP_CORRUPTED).

Result Code: VBOX_E_FILE_ERROR (0x80BB0004)
Component: ApplianceWrap
Interface: IAppliance {8398f026-4add-4474-5bc3-2f9f2140b23e}

I am receiving the following error on attempting to use a virtual appliance in Virtual Box. I have tried running it both in and out of the virtual machine. Any help with what this means would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to my problem. Due to the fact that I am using Virtualbox, all I needed was an update with the Insert Guest additions CD Image to work around